# I have a problem using rootGetters in Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I think it's a problem with rootGetters or data types.

```
// sheet.js

// character = Object
// number = 100

export const getters = {
  getNumber: state => {
    return Number(state.character.number); // its return 100
  }
};
```

and called getNumber to preview.js.

```
// preview.js
export const state = () => ({
  dummy: 0
});


export const getters = {
  numberIs: (state, rootGetters) => {
    return Math.round(state.dummy + rootGetters["sheet/getNumber"]); // undefined
  }
};
```

and numberIs return undefined.
What did I miss?

Comment: Just to be clear, your state with the dummy, it is not the same state as in your getter. (but you knew that)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order of the parameters matters. Vuex getter signature is `(state, getters, rootState, rootGetters)`, so currently what you think is `rootGetters` is actually just `getters`.

https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#accessing-global-assets-in-namespaced-modules

It's a little bit deceptive because of how actions pass in the context-object, where you can pick and choose what you want to use. Here you must use 4 parameters to get to rootGetters. (Or parse it out from arguments)

```
  numberIs: (state, _whatever, _idontcare, rootGetters) => {
    return Math.round(state.dummy + rootGetters["sheet/getNumber"]); 
  }
```